# Avoid text/shields from being too close using Mapnik xml

Tags: style, mapnik

I'm having the problem of text/shields from different layers appear too close to each other on the map generated from Mapnik xml.

The screenshot below shows the problem

[image]

I have three layers in this map.

1. A layer for shields, appeared as "rectangle 972" in the image
2. A layer for major roads, which has "SW 24th St" appear on the map
3. A layer for secondary roads

The problem is the "rectangle 972" and "SW 24th St" are too close to each other, and the street names for the secondary roads are also concatenated with each other (I'm less concerned with this though).

I couldn't find the right configuration option in Mapnik for this to look better. I have tried setting the minimum-distance in ShieldSymbolizer and TextSymbolizer, but I don't think that's the right way to do, and it didn't work of course.